# Doubling all elements in a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need help figuring out what is going wrong with my predicate to double all elements of a list. I am new to Prolog and am likely missing something very obvious. Basically my predicate should take a list (ex. [1, 2, 3]) and produce a list that has the elements doubled ([2, 3, 6]).

Here is what I have so far:

```
double_elements([], []).
double_elements([H|T], Doubled_list):-
  X is H*2,
  append([X], Doubled_list, Doubled_list),
  double_elements(T, Doubled_list).
```

However, my code currently just outputs "false" no matter what inputs I give it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Go look up the documentation for `append([X], Doubled_list, Doubled_list)`. You're trying to append `[X]` to something and unify it with the same something. That's always going to fail.

Comment: In Prolog, you cannot keep updating the same variable within a predicate clause.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to append [X] to something and unify it with the same something. That's always going to fail.

Try this instead:

```
double_elements([], []).
double_elements([H|T], [X|Doubled_list]):-
    X is H*2,
    double_elements(T, Doubled_list).
```

Comment: @lurker - Very true, pardon the pun.